# MVC 4 ASP.Net FORM submit() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a login form to work using the below method. I am using JQuery version 1.11.2 and MVC4. It appears that the problem is coming from this line of code

```
    <input type="button" onclick="getPasswordHash('password', 'nonce',     'hash');
    $('#loginForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Submitting form.. Please wait');
        return true;
    })" value = "Login"  />
```

This is the full code which is found in Login.cshtml

```
@model string

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

@section ExtraHeaders
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Login.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/sha256.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

}

<form action="@Href("~/Accounts/Login")" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/> Name <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> Password <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce" value="@Model"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="hash"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="getPasswordHash('password', 'nonce', 'hash');
$('#loginForm').submit()" value = "Login"  />

</form>
```

The getPassword method is found in the Login.js file

```
function getPasswordHash(passwordElement, nonceElement, hashElement)
{
    var password = $('#' + passwordElement).attr('value');
    var nonce = $('#' + nonceElement).attr('value');
    $('#' + hashElement).attr('value', $.sha256(password + nonce));
    $('#' + passwordElement).attr('value', '');
}
```

The problem is when I press Login nothing happens. The page does not refresh. It behaves as is I am clicking nothing.

EDIT: I have now checked the sources in developer tools of Chrome. It is telling me uncaught reference error: getPasswordHash is not defined

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNz6X.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because you told the submission event to *not* do its default behavior (which is to submit) when you used `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: put it back to .submit() still not working

Comment: The use of preventDefault is the issue. I cannot tell what you changed from here at this point, please edit your question to reflect your most current version.

Comment: Ok sure give me a sec

Comment: I have updated the last input line of code in form

Comment: this is what is happening now 

http://i.imgur.com/LOW9E0f.png

Comment: You may want to remove that carriage return in there so the js is all on the same line. In general, using inline event handlers is undesirable, so it would be best if you could move towards "unobstrusive javascript" practices.

Comment: Its hard to understand what your trying to do here. Your `<input type="button"..` certainly wont submit the form if that is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Database with users in it. To create the DB open the manager console and type `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName [ContextClassName]` this should create a migrations folder and then you need to register a user before signing in.

**EDIT**: Make sure you have a Login function inside of the Accounts controller

Comment: I'm sure this isn't your final db layout and just a proof of concept but you should never have a plain text password in your DB. Having said that, it looks like your backend code is looking for the hashed version of the password. Have you tried debugging the `function getPasswordHash(passwordElement, nonceElement, hashElement)` to see what its returnning

Comment: yes it is just a proof of concept. I did try to debug and apparently it is not even entering into the function. I tried to change type="submit" instead of type="button" and it will just redirect me back to posts with no admin access obviously. This goes to prove that the input command is only arriving to the type and completely disregarding the onclick functon